# Getting unexpected token by running code in JSR223 Sampler(groovy) in jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, jsr223

While running the below code in JSR223 SAMPLER, i am getting this error
Response code:500
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script989.groovy: 1: unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.
<HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy"

The code starts like this:

< HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy"
testname="Checkout Payment Info/Place Order${__property(activeAdminThread)}(${testLabel})" enabled="true">
< boolProp name="HTTPSampler.postBodyRaw">true

Error appearing for the very first line itself..what wrong in it ,plz help?

Comment: This isn't code/script, what are you trying to do?

Comment: This code is about magento performance toolkit ,which is similar to
https://gitlab.informatika.org/KIII-12/Magento/blob/91aa3072f58e3a4d53afa50ba7b95c110491ce4b/setup/performance-toolkit/benchmark.jmx

I am writing some code in which payment/shipping info is added and which will allow me to place a order without token as the bearer token comes from braintree which doesn't allow to access the token.
So  as an alternative,this code is required which is also giving me "unexpected token" for the first line mentioned in previous post.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code, it seems to be a part of [JMeter .jmx test plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) (pure XML file)

This [`HTTPSamplerProxy`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html?org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) is what's being used under the hood of the normal [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler so I would recommend going to where did you get this code, downloading it adding .jmx extension and opening it in JMeter GUI.

Answer (score 0):

**To solve the above issue you have to upgrade your JDK and JRE.**
Download the JDK and JRE and setup the Environment variable path
JAVA_HOME - JDK/bin
path - JRE/bin